# New to GIT: How do I import existing Python Eclipse/Pydev project in GIT Win64 local server?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git

I am totally new to GIT
Here is my environment:
-Win 10 x64 Pro
-Eclipse Neon Release 4.6.3 on Windows 10
-GIT 2.1.9 x64 on Windows 10

I have installed GIT and Eclipse already has EGIT installed
I am trying to figure out how to import an existing project in GIT

I am not sure what is the work flow in such a setup
I guess I continue to keep my sources in the folders where they are and Eclipse will continue to work with them. When I decide to commit (upload) a new version of my files I will probably use the Eclipse Plugin to upload the new version and this will do in the background all the work required to update the GIT local server repository

I have configured GIT with an user name and an email (both global and repository level) and EGIT picked that up immediately. Now I am trying to understand what are the steps I need to follow to create a copy of my Python project in the GIT local server

Can you please point me to the right direction? I have tried to use this tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html but  don't see where the existing Python project is copied to GIT

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Project name was hidden in the Package explorer window. All I had to do was to scroll up and then Right click on the Project name and from there use Team ...